# kontact cannot connect to akonadi server

Tags: kubuntu, akonadi, kontact, pim

I am facing troubles with getting kontact to run:

Installed it via:

`sudo flatpak install flathub org.kde.kontact`

Output of:

```
/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 

--command=kontact org.kde.kontact
Trying to create ksycoca...
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-cmd.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-cmd.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-ntf.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-ntf.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-ntf.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-ntf.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-cmd.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-ntf.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
Cannot initialize model with data QJsonObject(). missing: QJsonValue(string, "urls")
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-ntf.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-ntf.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-ntf.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-ntf.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-cmd.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-ntf.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-ntf.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-ntf.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-ntf.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi Client Session: connection config file 'akonadi/akonadiconnectionrc' can not be found!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name" "/home/benji/.var/app/org.kde.kontact/data/akonadiakonadiserver-ntf.socket"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to connect to server!
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Socket error occurred: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Socket error occurred: "Failed to connect to server!"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Socket error occurred: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Socket error occurred: "Failed to connect to server!"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Socket error occurred: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Socket error occurred: "Failed to connect to server!"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Socket error occurred: "QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Ungültiger Name"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Socket error occurred: "Failed to connect to server!"
```

Kontact is starting but does not connect to my dav calenderst/contacts (via nextcloud instance) So it looks as if it were a first-run (interstingly inside the settings, my calenders/contacts are showing up and telling me that everything is ready and in sync)

Any suggestions how I can solve this issue?

Kontact
Version 5.19.3 (21.12.3)
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-99-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,4 GiB

Comment: Hello. That is totally unreadable it is one super super long continuous sentence. A good start to an answer is to do some formatting to the question. At lease some line breaks.

Comment: Sorry should be done....

Comment: Any hints how to solve this problem?

Comment: Okay I just opened an report to kde bugs and flatpak github:
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=453121
https://github.com/flathub/org.kde.kontact/issues/71